# Prove the following properties of sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove the following are equivalent:

1. $E\in\mathcal{L}$  is the sigma algebra of lesbgue.
2. Exist a set $G$ which is an intersection of open countable sets such set $E\subset G$ and $m(G\backslash E)=0$ for lesbgue measure.
3. Exist a set $F$ which is a union of compact countable sets such that $F\subset E$ and $m(E\backslash F)=0$ for lesbgue measure.
   Ive managed to prove $(1)\to(2), (3)\to (1)$. Any hint or intuition for the rest please?

Comment: 1) implies 2) is regularity of Lebesgue measure. 3) implies 1) is immediate from completeness of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy my mistake i've updated the post